# Calling a function which is placed in an Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3, func

I have an array where I have the Title of Button as Key and the Image as Value  with position 0. I am calling this in CollectionView and the view looks like show in screenshot. At position 1 i have the name of the function that needs to be called with didSelectItemAt indexPath. How do I execute the function on click?

[image: View Shown when I execute collection view code and getting data from below array]

```
var mainBtnsArr = [
    ["Hotels" : ["homepage_hotel", ShowHotelSearch]],
    ["Flights" : ["homepage_flights", ShowFlightSearch]],
    ["Transfer" : ["homepage_transfer", ShowTransferSearch]],
    ["Activities" : ["homepage_sightseeing", ShowSightSeeingSearch]],
    ["Cruises" : ["homepage_cruise", ShowCruiseSearch]],
    ["CarRental" : ["homepage_carrental", ShowCarrentalSearch]],
    ["Packages" : ["homepage_packages", ShowPackageSearch]],
    ["Visa" : ["homepage_visa", ShowVisaSearch]],
    ["Groups" : ["homepage_groups", ShowGroupSearch]],
    ["Insurance" : ["homepage_insurance", ShowInsuranceSearch]],
    ["Meals" : ["homepage_meals", ShowMealsSearch]],
    ["ArrivalGuides" : ["homepage_arrivalguide", ShowArrivalGuidesSearch]]
]
```

My Collection View Code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
    let myCell:HomeCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HomeCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionViewCell
    myCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    myCell.layer.borderWidth = 1
    myCell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    myCell.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    let title = "\((mainBtnsArr[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary).allKeys[0])"
    let img = "\(((mainBtnsArr[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary).allValues[0] as! NSArray)[0])"

    myCell.imgIcon.image = UIImage(named: img)
    myCell.imgIcon.contentMode = .center
    myCell.imgIcon.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    myCell.imgIcon.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    myCell.imgIcon.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.colorFromCode(0xcccccc).cgColor
    myCell.imgIcon.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    myCell.imgIcon.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2.0, height: 2.0)
    myCell.imgIcon.layer.shadowRadius = 5

    myCell.lbl_Service.text = title
    myCell.lbl_Service.textColor = Constants.sharedInstance.MediumTextColour

    return myCell as HomeCollectionViewCell;
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("User tapped on \(indexPath.row)")
    //let funcToCall: = ((mainBtnsArr[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary).allValues[0] as! NSArray)[1]
    let funcToCall:CGFunction = ((mainBtnsArr[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary).allValues[0] as! NSArray)[1] as! CGFunction

}

// CollectionView Clicks
func ShowHotelSearch() {
    presenter.showHotelSearchScreen()
}
func ShowFlightSearch() {
    MyCustomAlert.sharedInstance.ShowAlert(vc: self, myTitle: StringClass.sharedInstance.lcStr_comingsoon, myMessage: StringClass.sharedInstance.lcStr_comingsoonflightstext)
}
```

Comment: What is happening now?

Comment: There is most definitely a better way to do this than how you are doing it now. Can you share a few of your methods? They might all be generic.

Comment: When I click on Collection View Cell. I want the function to be execute. Say If i click on Hotel, I want ShowHotelSearch To work

Comment: You are in wrong direction!!!

Comment: How about working with Tags and segregating based on those?

Comment: @iOSer - I know other methods. Just exploring to check if current method is possible or not.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri - I can manage this with other techniques. Is there a way to invoke the function mentioned in the Array on Click

Comment: **Unrelated:** It looks like you are using CLEAN architecture. Why does your presenter method name contain view specific information? Shouldn't it be something like `fetchHotelsForSearch` or something?

Comment: not recommending this, but if you select hotel `let selectedFunction = mainBtnsArr[0]["Hotels"]![1] as! ()->()` will assign the closure to a variable, and you can call it like `selectedFunction()`.  but @SPatel is right, wrong direction.

Comment: @meggar - will try your method and tell you if this works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using a `Dictionary` with a value which is an `[Any]` array to hold the button image name and function.  Then you have to do some ugly casting to get to something you can use:

```
if let funcToCall = myBtnsArr[indexPath.row].first?.value.last as? (HomeViewController) -> () -> () {
    funcToCall(self)()
}
```

You'd be better served to put this into a `struct` using proper types:

```
struct ButtonInfo {
    let title: String
    let image: String
    let function: (HomeViewController) -> () -> ()
}
```

**Note:** The property `function` is defined here to hold an instance function of the `HomeViewController` class.  When calling the function, the current instance of `HomeViewController` (i.e. `self`) will be passed like this: `function(self)()`.

Then define your `mainBtnsArr` like this:

```
let mainBtnsArr = [
    ButtonInfo(title: "Hotels", image: "homepage_hotel", function: ShowHotelSearch),
    ButtonInfo(title: "Flights", image: "homepage_flights", function: ShowFlightSearch),
    ButtonInfo(title: "Transfer", image: "homepage_transfer", function: ShowTransferSearch),
    ...
]
```

Then it is much easier to use the data.  (**Note:** Since the functions in the array are instance functions, you must pass `self` to the function when calling them):

```
let funcToCall = mainBtnsArr[indexPath.row].function
funcToCall(self)()
```

Likewise, `title` and `img` become:

```
let title = mainBtnsArr[indexPath.row].title
let img = mainBtnsArr[indexPath.row].image
```

Comment: Hi 
I am getting error while compiling for mainBtnsArr    -------->     
'(title: String, image: String, function: (HomeViewController) -> () -> ())' is not convertible to '(title: String, image: String, function: @escaping () -> ())'

Comment: Please use   static func ShowHotelSearch(){
        print("ShowHotelSearch")
    } instead of your old method

Comment: @YogeshTandel, check out my edit.  Since you are calling instance functions you need to specify the type as `(HomeViewController) -> () -> ()` in the `struct` and then pass `self` when calling the function.

Comment: @vacawama - Awesome bro. Works :)