# Uneven Dropshadows on rounded views

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview, calayer

I have collectionview cell to which I have a container UIView() which is margined at some distance from the super view. The containerview is rounded and I am trying to apply drop shadow to it. I am acheiving this quite finely until, on some cells it breaks the shadow layer and creates and uneven shadow effect. Following is  the current result.:
[image]

Following is my code:

```
extension UIView() {
    func dropShadow(color: UIColor, opacity: Float = 0.5, offSet: CGSize, radius: CGFloat = 1, scale: Bool = true) {
    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
    self.layer.shadowOffset = offSet
    self.layer.shadowRadius = radius

    self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: radius).cgPath
    self.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    self.layer.rasterizationScale = scale ? UIScreen.main.scale : 1
    }
}
```

Following is UICollectionViewCell.swift

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    containerView.dropShadow(color: .lightGray, opacity: 6, offSet: CGSize(width: 0, height: 0), radius: 6, scale: true)
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made use of shadow in a view inside collectionview cell. Please see below link

[View Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53652182/calling-a-function-which-is-placed-in-an-array)

This is inside cellforItem

```
myCell.imgIcon.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
myCell.imgIcon.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
myCell.imgIcon.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
myCell.imgIcon.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
myCell.imgIcon.layer.shadowRadius = 5
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I have already tried adding this. But this doesnt seem to work. I have tried plenty other ways as well. What do you suggest besides this?

Comment: can you share your code or screenshot of how your collectionview looks

Comment: Well I have shared the code above. And the cell from the collection view is also given. Do you want to see the whole collection view?

Comment: I also did trued pasting your code in `cellForItem`

Comment: add a UIView in your collectionview cell with margins of 100 on all sides and then add shadow to the view

Comment: Well At the moment my collectionview had a UIview to which the shadow is being applied. Thats on margin of 10 from all the sides and width, stretched all thought the screen frame

Comment: check the shadow offset values - myCell.imgIcon.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2.0, height: 2.0)

Comment: Yeah I saw it, I want more of a distributed shadow effect all around the edges. You can take AppStore Home page like card style. Hence offset was set to 0. Setting offset 2x2 will push the shadow bottom left, if I am not wrong.

Comment: Also, If I place my code in `layoutSubviews` in the `collectionViewCell` as it is now, then the cells randomly will display shadow properly and some will be left just as depicted in the picture above

Comment: If I change shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0) it shows shadow in 2 directions only. What value are you using?

Comment: I am using `somwview.layer.shadowOffset = offSet(width: 0, height: 0)` with a radius of 6. Thats how I am achieving this results. I tried your code exactly as you have written above and pasted in `cellForItem`. It didnt render the shadow

Comment: any possibility of sharing your code which I can run in xcode?

Comment: Hey, Its right here -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sq9Jsb00R-sjRE5RqSalL2-ovqULyWt0/view?usp=sharing Appreciate your time and help. I have reproduced the error in it. Tested on device

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185969/discussion-between-yogesh-tandel-and-aakash-dave).